# Reset state of a Redux store causing incosistent selectors with React Router

Tags: redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I'm experiencing a number of issues trying to reset my state of Redux when changing routes.
On enter in **routeA** and click browser history to **routeB**, after firing **@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE** for **routeB** it performs the selectors of wrong **routeA** and causes various undefined state errors.

It should not run the **routeA selector**, as i'm getting into **routeB** and I believe this is the problem but I have no idea how to solve it.

In some even happened to be showing duplicate keys in the state, sometimes by the way I'm trying to reset the state wrong.

**My scenery**

- In onEnter of the React Router i execute replaceReducers, see:

**My routes onEnter callback:**

```js
function onEnter() {
  replaceReducers({ book, dragAndDrop })
}
```

**replaceReducers:**

```js
function replaceReducers(reducers) {
  const appReducers = combineReducers({ ...reducers, ...defaultReducers })

  store.replaceReducer((state, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'RESET_STORE') {
      const { routing, application } = state

      state = { routing, application }
    }

    return appReducers(state, action)
  })

  store.dispatch({ type: 'RESET_STORE' })
  apollo.setStore(store)
}
```

Steps I followed and what happened the error:

- Enter **routeA**;
- Go to **routeB**;
- Click in browser history to **routeA**;
- **routeB** is called incorrectly;

Error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined in routeB-selector.js

getItems: book => book.get('items')
```

This **routeB** **selector** can not be called and something has run it automatically.

Help me, please...